# CLion LLDB doesn't break on uncaught exception

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, clion, lldb

I making a WinAPI DLL using CLion and debugging via LLDB debugger (inside CLion). So breakpoints work fine, however, if there's uncaught exception in my DLL target process crashes and debugger doesn't break when it does. But if there's exception in the target process, debugger breaks fine. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Perhaps you can switch to VS or WinDBG.

Comment: @user7860670 that's only way I found currenly, works but not really comfortable

Comment: I don't know how C++ exception throwing works on Windows.  lldb traps exception throws by putting a breakpoint on the function that starts the throw process.  On most Unix systems this is a single function from the C++ runtime support libraries.  It sounds from your description like exceptions from a DLL are propagated differently, and there's missing support for this in lldb.  If you have the time, please file a bug with http://bugs.llvm.org showing the problem and somebody on the Windows side should be able to fix it pretty easily.

Answer (score 2):

Did you enable breaking on exception in `Run` menu - `View breakpoints` window?

Answer (score 1):

this happens to me often and almost always the culpret is that the section marked `Disable until hitting the following breakpoint:` is set to `Any Exception`. simply change that value to `None` and the debugger will break when an exception is thrown.

i have no idea how or why this setting is changing itself to that value but, whenever it does, exception breakpoints stop working.

[image]